# Does the sequence $q(n)=3n+1+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}$ generate all the prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Define $$q(n)=3n+1+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2} \quad, \quad n\in \mathbb N.$$

$$1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,35,\dots$$

It seems like this formula gives all primes $>3$ (although not just primes of course), which is verified for all $n<1000$. Is it provable or are there counter examples?

Comment: It is provable. Of course it generates mainly non-primes.

Comment: I **hope** you mean every prime number can be written in that form, and not that ALL numbers in the sequence are prime. (25 and 35 are not prime.) Please edit and clarify what you mean.

Comment: $f(n)=n$ also gives all primes.

Comment: It appears that you are generating all odd numbers, except for those divisible by $3$. Naturally this will include all primes $>3$.

Comment: @barakmanos, yes and $2n+1$. Even I can prove that.

Comment: @Lehs: I was only trying to imply that there is nothing "remarkable" about this sequence of yours. You need to come up with a sequence which generates **all** primes and **only** primes, if you want it to be "remarkable" (BTW, there are plenty of those too, so I wouldn't even consider them as extremely remarkable).

Comment: Can you update your title to be descriptive of your specific question? It's really important for locating questions in the future, finding duplicates, and scanning questions on the main page and side bar.

Comment: @6005, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Lehs I updated your question for you this time. Generally, you should be able to get the entirety of the question from the title alone, if that's possible within the character requirement. Do you see how this title is more descriptive? Note that, if you still wanted to use the words "remarkable prime generator" you could include that in the title *in addition* to the specific definition of $q(n)$.

Comment: @mathguy I updated the question to include that, but really, I thought it was pretty clear before.  A 3000+ reputation user is not going to think that 25 and 35 are prime numbers

Comment: @6005, I didn't know that it was possible to search MathJax code.

Comment: @Lehs As of now, mathjax searching is not too good although it could get better in the future. What's far more important is the "Related questions" list and finding duplicates. Look at the sidebar of this very question: there is a related question entitled "a conjecture about primes", another "conjecture about primes and a certain q-series", and another "a conjecture concerning primes and algebra". You tell me, do you have any idea what those questions are before clicking on them? :)

Comment: On the other hand, in the sidebar: "disproving the twin prime conjecture for exotic primes" and "the asymptotic behaviour of triples $n! + q^{n!} = c$." These titles immediately give some good idea of what they are about and it makes a world of difference when navigating through related questions.

Comment: Anyway, it's important for the quality of the site, and as a high-rep user it would be very helpful for you to start using more descriptive titles. Don't take my word for it; meta explains this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $\,q(2k) = 6k+1,\ q(2k+1) = 6k+5$ and every prime $\,p>3\,$ has one of those forms, since by division $\, p = 6q+r,\ 0\le r\le 5\,$ and  $\,2\mid 6k,\,6k+2,6k+4\,$ and $\, 3\mid 6k+3$

Answer (score 7):

Since every prime above $3$ must be of the form $6k \pm 1$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, it stands to reason that this expression, which is essentially $6k \pm 1$ in different clothes, will produce all primes (in addition to the increasingly frequent composites).

Answer (score 4):

This is true.

Let $p>3$ be a prime number.  By division with remainder, we may write $p=6q+r$, where $0\le r<6$.  Now:

- $r$ cannot be $0$, because then $p$ would be a multiple of $6$.
- $r$ cannot be $2$ or $4$, because then $p$ would be a multiple of $2$.
- $r$ cannot be $3$, because then $p$ would be a multiple of $3$.

Therefore, $r=1$ or $r=-1$.  Now note that your sequence can be written as:

$$
0\times 6+1, 1\times 6-1, 1\times 6+1, 2\times 6-1, 2\times 6+1,3\times 6-1,3\times6+1,\dots
$$

so that it includes **all** positive numbers of the form $6n-1$ or $6n+1$.  By the argument above, this means that it contains all primes.  Of course, it also contains a lot of non-primes, such as $1$ and $25$, and the further along the sequence you get, the rarer the primes get.  So this is not much more remarkable than the observation that the sequence

$$
1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots
$$

contains all primes.